# PySimpleGUI disabled an InputText according to sg.Radio?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm new to PySimpleGUI,

I want to implement this functionality: There are two radio buttons. When I select one of them, the text input box below becomes editable. When I select the other one, the text box below becomes uneditable. This is my code. I've tried many times, but I can't achieve the dynamic effect I want. Could you guys help me?

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os as os


def main():

    sg.theme('Tan')
    column =[
        [sg.Text('sliding window?',font=('Microsoft Yahei',10)),sg.Radio('Yes','g',default=True,key='-Radio1-'),sg.Radio('No','g',default=False,key='-Radio2-')],
        [sg.Text('fill in',font=('Microsoft Yahei',10)),sg.InputText('3',key='-S_Window-',visible=True,disabled=False, enable_events=True)],
        ] 
    layout = [[sg.Column(column)]]
    
    # Create the window
    window = sg.Window('abcd', layout,resizable='True',finalize=True)


    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if values['-Radio1-'] == True:
            window['-S_Window-'].update(disabled=False)
            window.refresh()
        if values['-Radio2-'] == True:
            window['-S_Window-'].update(disabled=True,background_color = 'grey')
            window.refresh()

    window.close()

if __name__ =='__main__':
        main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRlXh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

With option `enable_events=True` in your `sg.Radio` elements to generate event when clicked, or it won't generate event when you click on them and no update for disabled state of  the Input element.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
layout =[
    [sg.Radio('Yes', 'g', enable_events=True, key=("Radio", 1)),
     sg.Radio('No',  'g', enable_events=True, key=("Radio", 2))],
    [sg.InputText('3', enable_events=True, key='-S_Window-')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif isinstance(event, tuple) and event[0] == "Radio":
        disabled = (event[1]==2)
        window['-S_Window-'].update(disabled=disabled)

window.close()
```

Comment: thank you very much Jason! It is exactly what I want!